# Delphi winsock why does sockaddr_in values get "garbled" when assigning InAddr.S_addr

Tags: delphi, winsock

I found a function to test if a specific tcp port is open on a remote PC. It appears to work alright, but when I assign a value to the variable `client.sin_addr.S_addr` the other values appear to be assigned with garbled values, well at least I didn't expect to see values like what I see.

Client record values before assigning `client.sin_addr.S_addr`:

```
(2, 39173, ((#0, #0, #0, #0), (0, 0), 0), (#0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0), 2, (#5, '™', #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0))
```

Client record values after assigning `client.sin_addr.S_addr`:

```
(2, 39173, (('À', '¨', #10, 'h'), (43200, 26634), 1745529024), (#0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0), 2, (#5, '™', 'À', '¨', #10, 'h', #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0))
```

Note that `1745529024` is the correct representation of the IP address `192.168.10.104`.

The function works as expected as far as I can see. I just don't like those garbled values.

Is this normal, should I worry, or just ignore it?

```
function PortTCP_IsOpen(dwPort : Word; InetAddress : AnsiString) : boolean;
var
  client : sockaddr_in;
  sock   : Integer;

  GInitData: TWSAData;
  ret : Integer;
  res : integer;
  msg : string;
begin
  Result:=False;
  ZeroMemory(@client, SizeOf(client));

  ret := WSAStartup($0002, GInitData); //initiates use of the Winsock DLL
  if ret <> 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    client.sin_family      := AF_INET;  //Set the protocol to use , in this case (IPv4)
    client.sin_port        := htons(dwPort); //convert to TCP/IP network byte order (big-endian)
    // before value
    client.sin_addr.S_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar('192.168.10.104'));     //inet_addr(PAnsiChar(ansistring(GetIPFromHost(InetAddress))));  //convert to IN_ADDR  structure
    // after value
    sock  := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);    //creates a socket
    Result:= connect(sock, client, SizeOf(client)) = 0;  //establishes a connection to a specified socket
    if Result then
    begin
      if not closesocket(sock) = 0 then
      begin
        res := WSAGetLastError;
        msg := SysErrorMessage(res);
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('%s Code:%d',[msg, res]);
      end;
    end else
    begin
      res := WSAGetLastError;
      msg := SysErrorMessage(res);
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('%s Code:%d',[msg, res]);
    end;
  finally
    WSACleanup;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a variant record, like a C union. Here it is:

```
type
  in_addr = record
    case integer of
      0: (S_un_b: SunB);
      1: (S_un_w: SunW);
      2: (S_addr: u_long);
  end;
```

So, `S_addr` holds the value `1745529024`, and the other two members are overlaid on the same memory. In hex, `1745529024` is `$680AA8C0`.

Now, what is `SunB`?

```
type
  SunB = record
    s_b1, s_b2, s_b3, s_b4: u_char;
  end;
```

So the debugger interprets the four bytes of `S_addr` as ANSI encoded characters, hence what you see in the debugger. Look up `$68`, `$0A`, `$A8` and `$C0` in your local ANSI table and you will find the four values that the debugger showed you.

Likewise for `SunW` which is:

```
type
  SunW = record
    s_w1, s_w2: u_short;
  end;
```

And the two words that make up `$680AA8C0` are indeed `$A8C0 = 43200` and `$680A = 26634`.

In summary, situation normal, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks to the two of you - of course it all makes very good sense now, not too familiar with C union and specially not that the memory space was shared.

Answer (score 3):

Those fields are declared as holding `Char` values, so the debugger interprets them that way and attempts to display characters. Of course, they're not really characters, but the debugger doesn't know any better.

The decimal value 1745529024 is hexadecimal 0x680AA8C0. The most significant byte is 0x68, which when interpreted as an ASCII character is lowercase *h*. The value 0x0A is a line feed, represented as a Delphi character literal as `#10`. And so on.